# Haskell. Assigning name to a threshold of values

Tags: function, haskell, threshold

I'm trying to figure out how to write in Haskell:

There is a list made of 4 variables: [w,x,y,z]
After completing the following through ghci:

```
collection :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> [Int]
collection w x y z = [w,x,y,z]
```

I want to assign a "meaning" to each threshold value for w,x,y,z. Example: when 0 < x < 60, then x = "Low", when 59 < x < 80, then x = "Medium", when 79 < x < 100, then x = "High"

How do you put that in Haskell code?

Answer (score 5):

If I understand correctly what you want, you can define a function that assigns what you call "meaning" to a single integer, and then map the collection list over it:

```hs
bin :: Int -> String
bin x
  | x <= 0    = error "nonpositive value"
  | x < 60    = "Low"
  | x < 80    = "Medium"
  | x < 100   = "High"
  | otherwise = error "value greater than or equal to 100"

binnedCollection :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> [String]
binnedCollection w x y z = map bin $ collection w x y z
```

For example,

```
Prelude> binnedCollection 0 20 60 80
["Low","Low","Medium","High"]
```

I have added error cases for the ranges not included in your definition; change them to whatever is appropriate for your logic.

Comment: That looks wonderful! Just to catch, what does "bin" stand for? Or maybe you could give a link to read about such notation. Thank you very much

Comment: Better yet, use a custom data type with *only* three possible values instead of `String` as the return value. `data Threshold = Low | Medium | High`, then `bin x | x < 60 = Low`, etc.

Comment: @chepner Nice suggestion!